# rails3 access nested session value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session-variables

Will probably seem like a very silly question. But here it is.

I am attempting to access via a helper method session data, which is nested by model.  Debugging data is as follows:

> session: {"session_id"=>"65bbe89c779cc89f3785a8ec181beee4",
>   "bozza_params"=>{"current_step"=>"2", "lavorazione_id"=>"7", [...]

Testing out first in the view, to ensure percolation, I fail to find proper syntax. The natural inclination I have is

```
<%= session[:bozza_params][:lavorazione_id] %>
```

But that and many other attempts are failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to use a hash syntax:

```
<%= session[:bozza_params]['lavorazione_id'] %>
```

This was actually answered elsewhere:
[Accessing data in a nested hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893109/accessing-data-in-a-nested-hash)